# How to disable Edittext keyboard?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I know that this question was asked before, yet non of the solutions worked for 
me.

All of the solutions i found include changing the focus when the edittext is clicked or disabling its option to be focused.

I'm  looking for another solution. Focus solutions did not work.

I did create a function that tells me if the keyboard is visible or not. (If that helps somehow).